# Python - Urllib how to get the website event result when scrapping data?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, urllib

I am scrapping the data from this website **to get the "Hosting Provider" result** from a website : https://digital.com/who-is-hosting-this

When I try scrapping the data by adding the website I'm looking for like this :
https://digital.com/who-is-hosting-this/#search=stackoverflow.com

I found that I don't get this part :
`<div id="lookup-results" class="lookup-box">`

This part only appears in "inspect" after I enter a Website URL and when you check the source code of the website it don't appears either.

I tried the "time.sleep(10)" that solved similar issues for some people but it don't seem to help, any ideas ?

Comment: Try using *selenium* due to the target website's reliance on JavaScript